# Query in rails with specific time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a query with a timezone I set in my application but the query is always grouping by the default UTC time zone. How can I use the time zone set in the config file?

I have the following code:

```
trans = table.order("date(created_at)").group("date(created_at)").limit(30)
trans.count.each do |key,value|
  labels_array.push key
  sales_array.push value
end
trans.sum(:amount).each do |key,value|
  revenue_array.push value
end
```

Comment: Which database engine? You'll need to do the time zone conversion within your call to `group`, and the syntax depends on what kind of database you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you set

```
# application.rb
config.time_zone = 'your timezone'
```

That's change Rails timezone but not ActiveRecard (continue save in UTC).
If you want change ActiveRecord timezone

```
# application.rb
config.time_zone = 'your timezone'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

My opinion - It's not really bad but I think that it's a good practice when the system is in UTC (database, cache, etc.).

You can group by with your timezone using SQL

```
 #mysql example
.group("DATE(CONVERT_TZ(your_field, 'UTC','<name of time zone>'))")
```

Comment: But it isn't a good idea to change the active record time zone right? It should be always UTC?

Comment: In postgresql it would be `DATE(your_field AT TIME ZONE 'timezone')` throws me `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "table.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`